# How long Memtest86 will take for 64G memory

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I have HPE c7000 chassis populated with gen9 blades with `64GB` memory. Recently i iLO was saying you have bad memory but i would like to check with memtest86 tool so i have started memtest86 to verify my iLO isn't lying. Its been 3+ hour this test is running and not saying any result so wondering how long this test will take and what is `PASS: 0` and `Errors:0` in this output?

Am i running wrong test?

[image]

HP iLO saying following

[image]

Comment: Note your Memtest86 sees and tests 48G.

Comment: It looks like your Memtest86 is not detecting and testing the 16GB memory that iLO says is degraded, so you will not learn anything from it (it’s only testing known good memory). I would assume the module in CPU 1 / Socket 1 is bad and replace it, or maybe test the module in another socket to make sure it’s the module that’s at fault and not the socket.